# Location of file in org.eclipse.xtext.common.ui.contentassist.TerminalsProposalProvider during xtext autocomplete

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I am currently working on an autocomplete feature for a xText generated language. To do this i extended the org.eclipse.xtext.common.ui.contentassist.TerminalsProposalProvider according to this: [How to write custom autocompletion in Xtext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423535/how-to-write-custom-autocompletion-in-xtext)

The problem i am facing now is that i need the path of the file while i am in the completeMyQL_Query(EObject model, Assignment assignment, ContentAssistContext context, ICompletionProposalAcceptor acceptor) function, i feel like it should be available somewhere in the ContentAssistContext, but i can not find it. Any ideas how to get the filepath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the context for a Resource. Or the current Model and that one for a (e)resource. The resource will give you an URI which might be what you are looking for

Comment: your answer helped me figure it out. In case anybody stumples upon this question, this is how i did it: File path = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
     .getFile(new Path(context.getResource().getURI().toPlatformString(true))).getLocation().toFile()
     .getParentFile();